# Google Script cannot Read Property "0"

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a code that will look the value of cell A3 in sheet `sheet1`, and check if it exists in column A in sheet `sheet2`.

What’s happening is that its working only when there are corresponding values. Otherwise, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined. (line 14, file "testing2")
```

Here is my code:

```js
function findInColumn(column, id) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var columntosearch = ss.getRange('TABELA DE HISTORICO DE PAGAMENTOS!A:A');
  var id = ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOSINDIRETOS!A3').getValue();

  var values = columntosearch.getValues();
  var row = 0;
  while (values[row] && values[row][0] !== id) {
    row++;
  }

  if (values[row][0] === id)
    ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!A3').copyTo(ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!A6'), {contentsOnly:true});
  else
    ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!D3').copyTo(ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!D6'), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the Javascript method indexOf will help you here. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control

I have changed your code a little bit to help you. There are comments inline to explain the changes.

```
function findInColumn(column, id) {
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //getValues returns a multidimensionalarray, so i am using reduce to flatten it
  var columntosearch = ss.getRange('TABELA DE HISTORICO DE PAGAMENTOS!A:A')
    .getValues()
    .reduce(function(a, b) {return a.concat(b);});

  var id = ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOSINDIRETOS!A3').getValue();

  //indexOf returns the index where the id is found or -1 if it isn't found
  var isInColumn = columntosearch.indexOf(id);

  //check that isInColumn is not -1
  if(isInColumn > -1) 
    ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!A3').copyTo(ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!A6'), {contentsOnly:true});
  else 
    ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!D3').copyTo(ss.getRange('TABELA CALCULADORA RETENCAO IMPOSTOS INDIRETOS!D6'), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Jordan, its working perfectly! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Great news! Glad to help

Comment: Hi Jordan, question: When the if condition is met, i would need to have the corresponding rows, 
in sheet 2, in column range I:O, having its values replaced by "0.00". Have been the whole day trying to find a solution, but i think my brain froze.
Could you give me a hand, or tell me what should i be looking for?

Comment: The value of isInColumn is the index of the row where the value is found. You can use this to getRange of the columns on that specific row and set the values that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
function valueOfA3insheet1inColumnAsheet2()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht1=ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');
  var rng1=sht1.getRange('A3');
  var valueinA3 = rng1.getValue();
  var sht2=ss.getSheetByName('sheet2');
  var rng2=sht2.getRange('A:A');
  var rng2A=rng2.getValues();
  var s='<table border="1"><tr><th>Value</th><th>Cell</th></tr>';
  for(var i=0;i<rng2A.length;i++)
  {
    if(rng2A[i][0]==valueinA3)
    {
      var r = sht2.getRange(i+1,1,1,1).getA1Notation();
      s+='<tr><td>' + rng2A[i][0] + '</td><td>' + r + '</td></tr>'
    }
  }
  s+='</table>';
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Values Found')
}
```